# Understanding the Entscheidungsproblem

Tags: logic, soft-question, computability

As a part of my self learning about Logic and Computability Theory, I'm trying to fully understand the Entscheidungsproblem and its unsolvability. However, it seems to me that many online resources do a rather poor job introducing it clearly.

I'd like to ask about the **exact formulation** of the problem. wikipedia describes it as

> finding an algorithm that considers, as input, a statement and answers "Yes" or
> "No" according to whether the statement is universally valid, i.e.,
> valid in every structure satisfying the axioms.

"
I'm assuming that "a statement" just means "a first-order sentence". But still, I don't understand what are "the axioms" reffered here. Should they also be an input for the algorithm? If so, this is quite limiting since we can only introduce a finite number of axioms. Or maybe the Entscheidungsproblem asks for such an algorithm **given* a set of axioms, so we essentially have a different "Entscheidungsproblem" for each set of axioms.

*An Introduction to Godel's Theorems* by Peter Smith describes the problem as deciding whether a given first-order sentence is "a theorem of first-order logic". I've never come across such notion before; I know what a theorem of a first-order theory is, but what is a theorem of *first-order logic* itself? In what first-order language would that sentence be written?

Comment: The axioms can themselves be algorithms of formulas as is typical in propositional logic. Check for example Godel's incompleteness paper where the "infinite" axioms are presented this way.

Comment: @Dole Is that indeed how Hilbert formulated it?

Comment: I have no idea. The second question, indeed you can put in any axiom scheme of any FO logic system and the algorithm should then answer what is valid.

Comment: It is notable that any axiom (with $\forall$) already can be initialized for any variable $v_1,v_2,....$, so an axiom that can be initialized for any $\phi$ conceptually is not a big difference. An infinite axiom schema is valid. Godel says "recursive/computable set of axioms", (though in the original it is only primitive recursive IIRC) in fact.

Comment: First-order logic is the theory with no non-logical symbols and axioms.

Answer (score 2):

See [Entscheidungsproblem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem) and the original 1928 formulation by [Hlbert and Ackermann](https://books.google.it/books?id=45ZGMjV9vfcC&printsec=frontcover) (§12. **The Decision Problem**):

> determining whether or not a given formula of the predicate calculus is universally valid.

Due to [Gödel Completeness Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem), we have that a formula is universally valid iff it is provable in the calculus: $\vDash \varphi \text { iff } \vdash \varphi$.

Thus, the problem amounts to determining whether or not a given formula of the predicate calculus is derivable form the axiom of [predicate calculus](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/#Dedu).

The unsolvability of the problem for predicate logic was showed by Alonzo Church in 1936: ["A note on the Entscheidungsproblem", Journal of Symbolic Logic, (1936)](http://people.csail.mit.edu/brooks/idocs/church_ent.pdf).

---

Consider the corresponding problem for propositional calculus: it is solved (in the positive) by the truth table method.

Comment: In which first-order language $\cal{L}$ are those formulas written? From what I've learned, the set of "axioms of predicate calculus" depends on the set of functional/relational/constant symbols that you have.

Comment: @35T41 - see [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/#Lang) for the standard specifications for first-order language.

Comment: @35T41 You have, in effect, different Entscheidungsprobleme for each (computable)  language $\mathcal L$. But if left unspecified, the traditional choice is a language with countably infinitely many $n$-ary relation and function symbols for each $n$. This is a "universal" language for logical validity as any sentence in whatever language only actually contains finitely many symbols, and presence or absence of extra symbols cannot change its validity.

Answer (score 0):

Mauro answered the historical question. As for the axioms, the limitation in these types of theorems is generally that the axioms are computable. That is there exists an algorithm to tell whether something is an axiom.

And indeed computable axioms can be infinite, for example

$$\forall \phi : \phi(0) \land (\forall n: \phi (n) \rightarrow \phi (n+1))\rightarrow \forall n \phi (n), $$

the axiom schema for induction, is an infinite computable axiom schema. In second order logic we often have axioms of the type "for all sets this holds", but then what is a "set" is left open or based on intuition or circumstances of the time. This is NOT what we are considering here, although is how some schools of mathematics operate.

Answer (score 0):

While I see many texts describe the Entscheidungsproblem as the problem of deciding first-order logic validity of a single sentence (as Mauro’s version does), I prefer to see the Entscheidungsproblem as the problem of deciding whether or not some given first-order logic sentence is a logical consequence of a given set of first-order logic sentences.

Notice that if you can decide logical consequence, then you can decide logical validity, because you simply pick the set of sentences to be empty. So, the logical consequence version feels more general than the logical validity version.

Also, this version relates more closely to the Wikipedia text: if you see a bunch of axioms as a set of statements, and theorems as those t that logically follow from it, then it is clear that we can also see the Entscheidungsproblem as the problem of deciding whether some sentence is a theorem or not.